# How to update/refresh the Power BI Report every very frequently where SharePoint List as Data Source

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, sharepoint-online, powerbi-embedded, sharepoint-list

I have a Power BI report using SharePoint List as data source. The SharePoint list data gets updated very frequently. Client want the latest data should get displayed over the PowerBI report in next 5-10 minutes or as soon as possible as those are critical data  and should be displayed instantly.

How to implement the refresh mechanism to refresh the report as quickly as possible?

Comment: You can try this https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh

Comment: Provide more details, for specific answer

Comment: The refresh frequency has two option such as daily and weekly. I need to refresh the Power BI report as soon as possible after the update at the source

Comment: It is possible with powerautomate flow. whenever there is a change in list, it will refresh powerbi dataset. Refer to this blog. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/blog/refresh-your-power-bi-dataset-using-microsoft-flow/ .It will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

For your use case you will be limited if importing data into the PBI report, Pro users allow 8 refreshes per day on a dataset, Premium Capacity or Premium capacity per users can have up to 48 times a day (every 15 mins).

For more Realtime, it would be best to get the data into a database table and use direct query to get the data, so the user gets the most recent data on report load. Use Power Automate/Logic Apps, or something like Azure Data Factory to get the data from there to the database.

If you do use direct query you can set the [report page refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-automatic-page-refresh), to load if the report is always open. However you will be limited to every 30 mins for Pro, and for Premium Capacity or Premium capacity per users you can use the default of 5 mins.

Comment: As an aside comment, confirm that real-time is actually real-time. If it was really critical data it wouldn't be in a SharePoint list, and if the report is only going to be used a few times a day, then report latency should not be an issue.  Client expectation is always as fast as possible, client use tends to be only used the report in morning, then two times per week